# find a specific Group in a layer and redraw it

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

i'm working in a project using kineticJS , i have inside a layer many Groups,
every group have many objects( img, text, events ...).

i wanna know if it's possible to find a specific group using id or name of the group and redraw it ?

Something like that :

```js
 var group = new Kinetic.Group();
    var layer= new kinetic.Layer();
    ///............
    var f_grp = group.find(".name");
    layer.draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, KineticJS documentation provides some examples:

```
// select node with id foo
var node = stage.find('#foo');

// select nodes with name bar inside layer
var nodes = layer.find('.bar');

// select all groups inside layer
var nodes = layer.find('Group');

// select all rectangles inside layer
var nodes = layer.find('Rect');

// select node with an id of foo or a name of bar inside layer
var nodes = layer.find('#foo, .bar');
```

You can find nodes by id, by name or by type.

Source: http://agavestorm.com/kineticjs/Kinetic.Group.html#find